# Google-services.json is missing from module root folder

Tags: java, android, google-analytics, google-analytics-firebase, google-play-services

To preface, I've got three product flavors, and I have added the google-services.json to each product flavor folder. I do not have a google-services in the root folder however according to the docs this is OK.

I keep getting this error when trying to generate a signed APK in Android Studio. If I run the project directly to my phone (debug build) it works fine, which is very odd.

I'm using the following version of the plugin in my project build.gradle:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.0.0-beta6'
```

According to the docs (https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin#introduction) since 2.0.0alpha3 there has been support for product flavors in the plugin.

I'm also using gradle-2.10-all.zip

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-beta6'
```

I'm trying to implement `Google Analytics V4` which says I need to use a google-services configuration file. So I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong, if anything at all.

Has anyone else come across this? Would appreciate any help on the matter, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Posted an issue about this on the google samples github repo

See issue here: https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/issues/186

In short this has been fixed by adding a google-services.json to the root/app folder which then gets overwritten by the google-service.json in each flavor folder.

Tested it and it works well. While it still might be a bug with the google services plugin and how it works, at least there is a workaround.